# Does adding a static constexpr member change the memory mapping of a struct/class?

Tags: c++, c++11

Note: This question arised in the context of shared memory between a C++ and C# program.

In C++11, does adding a `static constexpr` member change anything in term of memory mapping?
I would intuitively say that a `static constexpr` member doesn't occupy any memory, but I suppose I am ignoring some very fundamental aspect, like polymorphism for example...

So, in the following example, are an instance of Dummy and an instance of Dummy2 guaranteed to occupy the same amount of memory?

```
struct Dummy {
  static constexpr std::size_t kSize = 512;
  char data[kSize];
};


static constexpr std::size_t kSize2 = 512;
struct Dummy2 {
  char data[kSize2];
};
```

In [this test](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5ea1d4ff1f5902c0) this theory is not disproved, but I am very far from being able to say that this is guaranteed.

```
int main() {
    std::cout << sizeof(Dummy) << " " << sizeof(Dummy2) << std::endl;
}
```

> 512 512

Comment: A static non - `constexpr` doesn't change the memory mapping of a class *instance*. keyword there is `static`. So, why would making it constexpr be any different ?

Comment: @WhozCraig Can you refer me to a source for that? I could find this https://www.quora.com/Why-static-variables-do-not-contribute-to-the-size-of-objects-in-C++, but I am in trouble in finding the right search terms

Comment: 9.4.2 [class.static.data]  specifically states that static data members are "not part of the subobjects of a class." So, whether constexpr or not, they should take no footprint therein. All object sizing throughout the standard make specific language to ensure "non-static" when describing everything that is *anything* when it comes to members and their size contribution. I doubt that is by accident.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the language standard,

**9.4.2 Static data members [class.static.data]**

1. **A static data member is not part of the subobjects of a class**. If a static data member is declared thread_- local there is one copy of the member per thread. If a static data member is not declared thread_local there is one copy of the data member that is shared by all the objects of the class.

emphasis mine.

It doesn't matter whether it is constexpr or not; it's *static*, and as such is not part of instance composition.

Answer (score 1):

`Dummy` and `Dummy2` are *layout-compatible* (static members don't matter), see [class.mem/23](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#23).

However, the standard doesn't define what exact properties *layout-compatible* types have (it only defines when two types are *layout-compatible*, but doesn't say anything about the consequences). The intention must be that they have the same layout in memory, so you can assume that `sizeof(Dummy)` equals to `sizeof(Dummy2)`.

Comment: 22 and 23 together give a pretty clear explanation indeed. Maybe it's worth to coopy paste them here for posterity

Comment: [Standard layout](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Standard_layout) is also relevant.

Comment: @Antonio: if class types are layout-compatible, then they have standard-layout already.

Comment: Yep, it was more a note for myself.

Answer (score 0):

The language definition puts a few constraints on object layout, but within those constraints, the compiler has a great deal of leeway. The language definition does not require the layout to change when you add a static member, and it doesn’t prohibit it from changing. There’s no obvious reason for changing the layout, but there is no absolute answer. It probably won’t change, but if it really matters, try it and see.

Comment: I think from geza answer static members are supposedly not allowed to change the layout.

Comment: @Antonio -- that's right for **standard-layout** classes. It's not true in general.

Comment: "it doesn't prohibit it from changing" is then not true in many cases: for [standard-layout classes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Standard_layout) it is indeed prohibited. I think that is worth underlining, also because it matches the example that goes with the question.